# Identifying number in a string and replace - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to replace all `:` (colon) with `:`  (colon space). I am able to do this with replace function.

```
description_string = Replace(currentSheet.Cells(i, j), ":", ": ")
```

but this replace time formats (eg `16:20`) also. I need to identify the colons `:` which has number as a preceding value (eg. `9:`)

i have tried using regular expressions

```
[a-zA-Z]:[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

as the pattern. The issue is how will I replace only colon from this. If I try replacing, the entire characters before and after the colon is getting replaced.

I tried find and replace but the issue is for the string like

**abcd Date:01/01/17 10:18 Des:xyz**

all the colons are getting changed to :

The output I want is

**abcd Date: 01/01/17 10:18 Des: xyz**

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to replace if there is a number before the colon?

Comment: Look up "using regular expressions in vba" - that will give you want you need to solve the problem.  If you are still having trouble once you've found a few examples (there are literally hundreds on [so]) come back and clarify the question or post a new one.

Comment: How about using Regular Expresions? [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: @SJR yes. I don't want to replace if there is a number before the colon?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Use regexp as suggested, or do a check of the position of the colon (Instr) and check the preceding character before replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regular expression pattern

```
reg.Pattern = "(\D:)" ' non-digit followed by colon, as group $1
```

`\D` specifies a non digit character. (\D:) specifies a non-digit character followed by colon. Parenthesized, this matched pattern will be identified as `$1` in the replacement later; because it is the first (and only) captured group.

Then replace like this:

```
newString = reg.Replace(oldString, "$1 ") 'replace captured group by itself then space
```

Replaces the matched group (`$1`) by itself followed by space: `"$1 "`

An alternative in cases of only one group in the pattern (like this one), you can drop the parentheses and identify the (only) captured group as `$+`.

```
reg.Pattern = "\D:" ' non-digit followed by colon, as the only group ($+)
newString = reg.Replace(oldString, "$+ ")
```

---

```
Sub Example()
  Dim reg As New RegExp: reg.Global = True: reg.Pattern = "(\D:)"
  Dim oldString As String: oldString = "abcd Date:01/01/17 10:18 Des:xyz"
  Dim newString As String: newString = reg.Replace(oldString, "$1 ")
  Debug.Print newString
End Sub
```

> ```
> abcd Date: 01/01/17 10:18 Des: xyz
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much [A.S.H.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) . This helped me a lot. Can you please help me understand how the replace function worked in this scenario?

Comment: @ManuMohan you're welcome. There are some exaplanations as comments in the answer. `\D` specifies a non digit character. `(\D:)` specifies a non-digit character followed by colon. parenthesized means this matched pattern will be identified as `$1` in the replacement. Finally, the replacement replaces the matched group (`$1`) by itself followed by space.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ASH.. i just got confused by '$1'. So my understanding is $1 will be always the string identified by the regexp. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ManuMohan $1 is the first "parenthesized" group (here it's the only one). An alternative in cases of only one group would be to not use parentheses and identify the (only) captured group as `$+`. `.Pattern = "\D:"` and `reg.Replace(oldString, "$+ ")`.

Comment: I added these explanations to the answer.